# Delphi, Csv,Import Firebird

Tags: delphi, csv, firebird

Lemme explain my problem. 
I have One ID and 2 Other Fields in a CsV file. the ID connected to a database table. 
I have to show the curresponding entries in the db and fields from Csv. Need sort the Fields too. 
My Idea was load into a ClientDataset, lookup to a Query with table and Use sort and show. 
My Csv have 85 K Records and its taking 120 seconds to load and sort, Its not acceptable. Can you tell me, can I use Bacthmove for this. So I can easily pick fields by a simple query. if I can use Batchmove please give me the guidelines.

Also Is there any other Techniques for this?

Thanks and Regards,
Vijesh V.Nair

Comment: If it's a one-time-job, 120 seconds is OK. If you need to do this multiple times, why are you looking at some external data pumping application (Batch Move)?

Comment: "can't Use" what? If you want help, you need to be more specific. Is this something you need to do once, or every time you run your application?

Comment: If something is too slow for you, you need to use a profile tool to find out what takes most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can take a look in [global temporary table](http://www.firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rlsnotes210.html#rnfb210-globaltemp) but I don't think it will be quicker

Answer (score 0):

i often convert database from csv file to firebird server too.
usually i do like these
 - use ms excel to read this csv file first to see if this file is not corrupt.
 - still using excel, save this csv file to xls format, close ms excel after converting.
 - using axolot component (xlsreadwrite) (www.axolot.com) , try to read cell by cell and insert them to memory table.
 - using fibplus component (www.devrace.com), insert them to firebird server.
 - job done, going home.
In this case, of course you must prepare your firebird server too. After converting finished, everything is easy actually. you can use uib component (www.progdigy.com) too to connect to firebird server. do not use ibexpress component (ibx) cause of it's author EXPLICITLY state that ibx is never intended for firebird.